# Enabling CORS through Web.config vs WebApiConfig and Controller attributes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

There seems to be two functionally different ways to enable cross-origin request sharing in Web API 2.

One is to import `System.Web.Http.Cors`, **decorate a controller** with the `EnableCors` attribute and to write `config.EnableCors()` in the WebApiConfig:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://111.111.111.111", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class GenericController : ApiController
{
    // etc.
```

The other is to **modify the Web.config**:

```
<system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://111.111.111.111" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
```

Is there a functional difference between these two different approaches?  Which one is correct - don't these accomplish the same thing?  If both methods are used to enable CORS, will things blow up?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you add the headers to the web.config, **every** request that is served by that application will include the specified headers. This method is supported at the web server level and doesn't depend on `config.EnableCors()` being executed. You can use that method to add any HTTP header you want.

On the flip side, the `EnableCors` attribute requires WebAPI and you need to add some code to make it work. To the end user, the result is the same.

As for which way is better? I've liked keeping those settings in the application code by using the attribute so these settings are obvious to future developers. Depending on your needs, you may want to look into a abstract `CorsApiController` which your main ApiControllers could inherit to deliver the same CORS headers over and over. But this method won't work if the CORS headers need to vary from controller to controller or from action to action.

Comment: Makes sense - so the `System.Web.Http.Cors` namespace is just around for added flexibility in large projects where multiple controllers may need to have different cross-origin request sharing rules.  Thank you very much!

Comment: When you add headers to web.config, is it still necessary to install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package for them to work? Or is this a separate strategy completely from installing the nuget cors package?

Comment: @Kyle completely different strategies. Choose one or the other. In the web.config case, you can't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for a list of acceptable orgins.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Setting up the CORS policy via IIS provides  a more flexible way to configure your application if it needs to support another client or the address of the existing one changes.

Comment: Very interesting topic, I have been enabling CORS for my web app using web.config, found it working, but I think enabling through code has much power & security, maybe depends on the project you are working, I think more easy way is through web.config if you dont care much about the extent of CORS

Comment: Adding we.config headers CAN be limited to specific paths by using the `<location path="">` tag. An entire directory or specific file may be used for the Path attribute value.