# Api call from within WCF project to another WCF Project error

Tags: c#, wcf, cors

I'm having some big problems with understanding why i get "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin" 
So to understand better my webapi project has a method for login. That method calls another api (different server) for login to receive a token. In the client i  add the header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*") when i make the call to the other project. I also enabled cors on Azure. I even added above the method   [EnableCors(origins:"*",headers:"*",methods:"*",exposedHeaders:"*")].

This is a peak of my webconfig

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="c:\SAB.Hosting.WebApi.Log.Xml" />
    <add key="LoginAddress" value="https://somewebsite/api/account/Login" />
    <add key="GetToken" value="https://somewebsite/api/account/GetToken" />
    <add key="RegisterAddress" value="https://somewebsite/api/account/Register" />
    <add key="LogoutAddress" value="https://somewebsite/api/account/Logout" />
    <add key="RegisterAddress" value="https://somewebsite/api/account/Register" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

Updates: I found out that the problem is not from the links above.This is happening when i add SSL certificate between my api project and my wcf services.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="PersonService_HttpEndPoint" />
        <binding name="SABService_HttpEndPoint" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="PersonService_TcpEndPoint">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="SABService_TcpEndPoint">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="93F67C44F8RB0DC5FD1CA8013F256B8F84C8E08G" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
            <!--<clientCertificate findValue="PFX" x509FindType= "FindByExtension" />-->            
          </clientCredentials>
          <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://someaddress/SABService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="CertBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SABService_HttpEndPoint" contract="SABServiceReference.ISABService" name="SABService_HttpEndPoint" />
      <endpoint address="https://someaddress/PersonService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="CertBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PersonService_HttpEndPoint" contract="PersonServiceReference.IPersonService" name="SABPersonService_HttpEndPoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I don't know why if i add the ssl certificate throws no access-control-allow-origin on login.

Waiting for your solutions.

Thank you,
A fallen programmer in need.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable CORS explicitly in your `WebApiConfig` using [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors) nuget:

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    // ...

    public void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("<origins>", "<headers>", "<methods>")
        {
            SupportsCredentials = true // If you need to pass them
        });

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i am not using MVC, I am using webconfig. This can be added in webconfig too?

Comment: @user2964720 AFAIK using web.config you can only add static headers to every response. See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970793/enabling-cors-through-web-config-vs-webapiconfig-and-controller-attributes

Comment: @user2964720 By the way, this solution is not only for MVC projects. It can be used for any web application hosted by OWIN as well.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help, but please check what i added now. I've added an update to my problem.