# blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a web site 1 and a Web API 2
My Web API have a method name

```
 public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello world from site 2";
        }
```

In the controller Values.
I call from the web site 1 my API like that

```
$.ajax({
            url: relativeUrl,
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken },
            type: "GET"
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                console.log("Result: " + result);
                alert(result);
            })
            .fail(function (result) {
                console.log("Error: " + result.statusText);
                alert(result.statusText);
            });
```

But I have the following error in my js console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘Web API 2' from origin ‘Web site 1’ has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I add in my controller :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header")]
```

In my WebAPIConfig.cs

```
config.EnableCors();
```

And in my Web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But even with that I have still the error, I don't understand what I need to add and where.

Comment: Are you running both the website and the API on your `localhost`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've got

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

and

```
headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken },
```

In other words, the Access-Control setting only allows the "content-type" header, but your request is sending an "Authorization" header. Clearly these two things don't match up.

The error is very clearly telling you that the "authorization" request header is not being allowed by the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header.

Try

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
```

instead.

P.S. I don't think you need to use both the web.config settings *and* the EnableCors action filter at the same time. I think your EnableCors declaration here is redundant. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972098/5947043 for more info.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers for more info

Comment: that true is redondant. I was not focus on the token because is empty, so I didn't see what it was just in front of me. Thank, that work perferctly now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know abouth this, But I have faced same problem in Node.
I think if you change this

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

to

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
```

or

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization" />
```

since you are calling Authorization header.

Comment: Yep, changing ```value``` to ```value="*"``` fixed it for me as well

Comment: It's nice to hear that I was able to help you! 

Comment: Correct! The special value Authorization is also needed in particular for (serverless) Cloudflare Workers CORS, not only for a generic node.js traditional app.